# Slick slider jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui

Can I put an anchor or something on jQuery UI slider elements, so that the elements from one slide can be accessible as a link or something? Also, how show my url look like? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location) to link to that value. E.g. http://myurl.com/test#10 will set the slider value to 10:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').slider({ value : window.location.hash });
});
```